# Reference const to bitfield value

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Is it safe to create a reference const to a bitfield value?
Have a look in the following example

```
typedef struct
{
    int a:1;
}x_t;

int main() {
   x_t x;
   bool const &  x2 = x.a; 
}
```

Comment: It's *safe*, but not very useful. Is this just curiousity or are you hoping to achieve something in particular by doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to create a reference const to a bitfield value?

Yes, it's like the same as if you would write for example:

```
bool const& x3 = 42;
```

In your code the value of `x.a` is taken and a temporary object of type `bool` is created with the value of `x.a` assigned to it and then the reference is bound to that temporary object. So it's like creating a "view" (it's `const`) of the current value of `x.a` as a `bool` type. In oversimplification let's say it works as-if like:

```
const bool _some_hidden_temporary = x.a;
bool const& x2 = _some_hidden_temporary;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll get is a `const&` to a temporary. if you toggle the bit in `x_t` it will not be reflected via the `const&` (`x2`).

The lifetime of the temporary is the lifetime of `x2` (the end of `main`).

You can't have references to individual bits (in a bitfield) without implementing some kind of proxy class.

Comment: Until which point is the lifetime of this ?

Comment: @getsoubl I added that to the answer